# how to put caption (a) below 2 pictures

Tags: captions

[image]

I am rephrasing my question...
I want to obtain attached Image.. I have coded as below.. But I do not obtain required output.. Can you help me modify my code?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{c1.eps}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{c2.eps}
\caption{}%{V} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{c3.eps}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{c4.eps}
\caption{}%{P} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Variation} \label{fig:wind_speed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: I think you can use the package [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) suitable for solve your problem.

Comment: please see modif question.. i add my code.. also the code reproduce the picture i posted

Comment: Good, but that isn't still a full MWE. Complete it please.

Comment: ermm this is the full code actually for the pict..

Comment: So, basically, you want the figures to be "numbered" with alphabetic letters rather than with Arabic numerals, and you don't want the letters preceded by "Figure"? Please confirm.

Comment: yeah mico this is exactly what i want

Comment: @IZNA -- Sorry, I am totally confused. Now you want the Prefix Figure: My second attempt below is what you want, except you need to fill in `V` for caption (a) and `P` for caption (b) and change the word `variation` to `(a) some text (b) some text`.

Comment: @Jesse it does not work... i obtain this see in question new pic..

Comment: @Jesse i copied ur code and mofif according to my file.. but i obtain as attached.. i dunno why the figure 1 and figure 2 remained!

Comment: @IZNA -- I run the latest code you provided and did not observe any Figure 1 and Figure 2 as shown in the image on the top. My wild guess is that you have two extra `\caption{}` inserted after `\end{subfigure}` and that command issues another prefix `Figure`. Note the system may think we are chatting. If still have question, let use chat room.

Comment: Are the strings "Figure 1" and "Figure 2" supposed to be there?By the way, I've taken the liberty of deleting copies 2 and 3 of what appeared to be three instances of the same image.

Comment: @Mico i DO NOT WANT TO SEE FIGURE 1 AND FIGURE 2,, ONLY (a) and (b)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Jesse i assure you the exact way i post the code is the exact results i obtained.. this is soo frustrating..:(

Comment: @IZNA - did you see my fully updated answer? No more "Figure 1" or "Figure 2"... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Would this be what you seek? Use of `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` package

Update: second attempt

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
   \centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-A} 
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-B} 
\caption{}%Vacoas}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-C} 
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-A} 
\caption{}%{Plaisance}
\label{fig:b} 
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Variation} 
\label{fig:wind_speed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:f1} 
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:f2}
\end{subfigure}
\centering
\caption{(a) Some text (b) Some text}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no.. i seek the (a) to be in the place of Figure 1.. below both pics i do nt want any labels.. i want it to be centralised.

Comment: So add a full MWE not only what you consider the enough lines of the image: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: hi.. the second attempt is exactly what i wanted!!! but the Figure 1 and figure 2 still does appear belwo..:( see image in question

Comment: @IZNA -- In my example, just mark them out as displayed below %\caption{Variation} 
%\label{fig:wind_speed}

Comment: i want variation to appear, ONLY FIGURE 1 AND FIGURE 2 WHICH I DO Not want.. see ur code with my data..

Comment: \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{wind_vacoas.eps}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Wind_Rose_Yearly_vacoas.eps}
\caption{}%{Vacoas}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{wind_plaisance.eps}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Wind_Rose_Yearly_plaisance.eps}
\caption{}%{Plaisance}
\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Variation of wind speed and direction measured by MMS at
the two sites}
\label{fig:wind_speed}
\end{figure}

Comment: @IZNA -- So you still want the caption but to turn off the prefix `Figure:` Then use this in your preamble `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}`.

Comment: still no change...:( @Jesse

Comment: @IZNA More methods in this direction -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842322/removing-prefix-from-figure-captions-in-latex.

Answer (score 2):

(answer thoroughly revised after OP's posting was edited/modified)

I'm afraid the screenshot you've posted of what you say you want isn't entirely self-explanatory. E.g., what are the two isolated strings "Figure 1" and "Figure 2" doing, and are they needed? For now, I've decided to not to try to generate them, especially as there's no hint of them in the code you've posted.

I would suggest taking the following steps:

- Provide one `\caption` command per `subfigure` environment, and one more for the overall `figure` environment.
- Use a `\centering` instruction both at the start of the main `figure` environment and at the start of each of the two `subfigure` environments.
- If you want just the subcaptions' letters -- `(a)` and `(b)` -- but no other text, just type `\caption{\null}`.
- To get the captions' text -- including the letters letters `(a)` and `(b)` -- typeset in **bold**, set the option `font=bf` when loading the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. I set this option based on the screenshot you posted. Obviously, if you don't want bold, don't specify this option.
- I've set `\qquad` ("double quad") as the horizontal separation between the two images on each row; adjust this to suit your needs. Likewise, I've inserted `\bigskip` to separate the two subfigures vertically; adjust as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option for real document
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{c1.eps}
\qquad  % choose separation between c1 and c2
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{c2.eps}
\caption{V} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{c3.eps}
\qquad  % choose separation between c3 and c4
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{c4.eps}
\caption{P} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{(a) and (b) represent circles} \label{fig:wind_speed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```